# How to fetch tables and their corresponding column names used in stored procedures using t-sql?

Tags: sql

I just want to get the tables and their corresponding columns which are written as a part of stored procedure using t-sql? How can I get a list of the same? Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server or sybase? The SQL tag is for the standard SQL language, and both SQL Server and Sybase use the name T-SQL for their variant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have table names with you, use following query to get the required details as:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,IS_NULLABLE,COLUMN_DEFAULT,TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('TBL1','TBL2') ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following effort to get my query resolved.

```
SELECT distinct sp.name as StoredProc, tbl.name AS [Table], col.name AS [Column]
FROM sysobjects sp
INNER JOIN sysdepends sd ON sp.id = sd.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects tbl ON tbl.id = sd.depid
INNER JOIN syscolumns col ON col.colid = sd.depnumber AND col.id = sd.depid
WHERE sp.name IN ( SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE id IN(SELECT id from syscomments         
WHERE text LIKE '%passParamToGetYourSPs_%'))
--group BY sp.name
--AND sp.name = 'Search_SP_Name'
ORDER BY sp.name, tbl.name, col.name
```

Thanks for all your efforts. Smile | :)